# Link Info in Infopath to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, power-automate

Can I export or link data from Infopath files (in a sharepoint library) to single excel in another sharepoint

1. with existing Infopath files?
2. whenever a new infopath file modified?

Comment: Can you please explain your application further?  How do you mean ‘link to an Excel file in another SharePoint’?  Is InfoPath supposed to be writing to that excel file?  Is the excel file supposed to be displaying the data from the InfoPath form?

Comment: Sure. The excel file is to display the infopath content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the “Export to Excel” function via the list or library ribbon “Export to Excel” button, whuch causes the browser to download a query.iqy file, and depending on your configuration, may attempt to open the file.  The default executable that handles an *.iqy file is Excel.  Upon opening you will see the list or library columns in a a sortable table.  You can further enhance this experience by enabling the file to update the data every time it is opened by exploring the Data tab in Excel and saving the file as an xlsx.

Mark this as a answer if this helped you.